# Routing the requests to rails concerns based on the incoming request type

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails version is 6.0.0.3 and Ruby version is ruby 2.6.6-p146

I need to send the incoming request to the application controller to 2 different concerns based on the request format.

I have an application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Authentication
  include Authorization

  before_action :authenticate_or_authorize

  private

  def authenticate_or_authorize
    request.format.json? ? :authorize_request : :authenticate_request
  end
end
```

I have 2 concerns namely authentication and authorization. if the incoming request is of type JSON, I need to call the authorization concern.

If it is a non json request i need to call authenticate_request.

Here are my concerns.

```
module Authentication
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :authenticate_request, :return_url
  end

  private

  def authenticate_request
    // do something to authenticate
  end
end
```

Here is the second concern.

```
module Authorization
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ::JwtVerifiable

  included do
    before_action :authorize_request
  end

  private

  def authorize_request
    // do something to authorize.
  end
end
```

The current behavior is request always goes to the Authentication concern. Then afterward comes to the authenticate_or_authorize defined in the ApplicationController.

Can anyone help to correct the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Concerns are already providing their own `before_action` calls when they are included (that's what `included do (block) end` is doing).  This means that :authenticate_request, :return_url and :authorize_request are going to be run on every request.  If you can't remove those from the concerns themselves, you skip them with:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_request, :authorize_request
```

after including the concerns in ApplicationController.  The `before_action` you've defined in ApplicationController will still run.

Comment: I did not understand. You mean to add the skip_before_action in the application_controller before the before_action? Then the before_action : authenticate_or_authorize will do the needful ?

Comment: skip_before_action just needs to be after the 2 include statements.  Putting it directly above your "skip_action" is a good place for it.